# Execute Django command within Django variable

Tags: python, django, otree

I would like to read a string from an excel-file with both HTML- and Django-Tags (e.g. "Your current < b > account balance </ b > is: {{ current_balance }}").
I then pass the variable from the python-file to the Django-template (name e.g. balance).
When I try to call the variable in the Django-template using {{ balance }}, I get the displayed the whole variable as a string. If I use {{ balance | safe }} the HTML-tags are executed. Is there a way such that the Django tags get executed as well?

Here's my code:

In pages.py:

```
class page(Page):
    
    def vars_for_template(self): #define variables to pass to tempalte
        
        loc = ("file.xlsx")

        # To open Workbook
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
        sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

        # For row 0 and column 0
        variable = sheet.cell_value(0, 1))


        print(title)
        return dict(
            variable=variable
        )
```

In page.html:

```
{% extends "global/Page.html" %}
{% load staticfiles otree %}

{% block title %}

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   {{ variable | safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

the value of `variable` is `the current value is <b>{{ Constants.value }}</b>` 
In the output, only the HTML-tags get executed an I receive "the current value is **{{ Constants.value }}**". Is it possible to display the actual value of the variable `Constants.value`?

Comment: Could you please add a sample of your code?

Comment: Sorry, just added the code to my original post

Comment: I'm note sure you can do this directly in the Django template. Why don't you format the string before giving it to the template?

Comment: Thanks al lot Nathan, it worked!
I only had to change the substitute the {{ Constants.value }} part in the variable to { placeholder } and then could set the value of this placeholder with variable=variable.format(placeholder=Constants.value) in pages.py,